# How do I access the root of the GitHub Repository in a GitHub action?

Tags: pdf, latex, github-actions

I am trying to build a resume pdf from a `resume.tex` in my resume [repository](https://github.com/adityamwagh/resume) file whenever a commit is made.

I am getting the following error.

```sh
Error:  File '/home/runner/work/resume/resume/resume.tex' cannot be found from the directory '/github/workspace'.
```

How should I access the `resume.tex` file? If I just say `root_file: resume.tex`, the error is:

```sh
Error:  File 'resume.tex' cannot be found from the directory '/github/workspace'.
```

The `.github/workflows/build_resume.yml` file looks like this. The `resume.tex` file is in the root of my [repository](https://github.com/adityamwagh/resume).

```yaml
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: Build PDF on commit.

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the main branch
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
#   workflow_dispatch: 

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      - name: Github Action for LaTeX
        uses: xu-cheng/latex-action@v2
        with:
          # The root LaTeX file to be compiled
          root_file: ${{ github.workspace }}/resume.tex
          # Interpret the root_file input as bash glob pattern
#           glob_root_file: # optional
          # The working directory for this action
#           working_directory: # optional
          # The LaTeX engine to be invoked
#           compiler: # optional, default is latexmk
          # Extra arguments to be passed to the LaTeX engine
#           args: # optional, default is -pdf -file-line-error -halt-on-error -interaction=nonstopmode
          # [Deprecated] Install extra packages by tlmgr
#           extra_packages: # optional
          # Install extra packages by apk
#           extra_system_packages: # optional
          # Install extra .ttf/.otf fonts.
#           extra_fonts: ./fonts/*.ttf
          # Arbitrary bash codes to be executed before compiling LaTeX documents
          pre_compile: tlmgr update --self && tlmgr update --all
          # Arbitrary bash codes to be executed after compiling LaTeX documents
          post_compile: latexmk -c
          # Instruct latexmk to enable --shell-escape
#           latexmk_shell_escape: # optional
          # Instruct latexmk to use LuaLaTeX
#           latexmk_use_lualatex: # optional
          # Instruct latexmk to use XeLaTeX
          latexmk_use_xelatex: true
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you want to execute files from the current repository, you need to use the [actions/checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout) first (at the beginning of your job's steps).

This will allow you to access the repository `$github_workspace` (one of [Github environment variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/environment-variables)) in your workflow.

*Note: All commands you'll run after using the `action/checkout` will be executed at the repository root.*

For example, considering that your `resume.tex` file is at the root of the repository, you would use something like this:

```
   name: Example

   on:
     push:
     pull_request:

   jobs:
    build:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      steps:
      - name: checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.4
      - name: show resume.tex file content
        run: cat resume.tex
```

[Here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/03-python-script-workflow.yml) is another workflow example from a personal repository, following the same logic if you want to execute a specific script located in the repository in your workflow. to perform any operation.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking to do the same, the following steps need to be done.

- Go into your repository.
- Compile latex document using [xu-cheng/latex-action@v2](https://github.com/xu-cheng/latex-action)
- Check if PDF is generated.
- Push PDF to repository.

The configuration file to do that will look like this.

```yaml
name: Github Actions CI to build pdf from tex source.
on: push
jobs:
  build:
    if: "!contains(github.event.head_commit.message, '[skip ci]')"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Set up Git repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Compile LaTeX document
      uses: xu-cheng/latex-action@v2
      with:
          # The root LaTeX file to be compiled
          root_file: resume_aditya_wagh.tex

          # Interpret the root_file input as bash glob pattern
          # glob_root_file: # optional

          # The working directory for this action
          # working_directory: # optional

          # The LaTeX engine to be invoked
          # compiler: # optional, default is latexmk

          # Extra arguments to be passed to the LaTeX engine
          args: -pdf -file-line-error -halt-on-error -interaction=nonstopmode

          # Install extra packages by apk
          # extra_system_packages: # optional

          # Install extra .ttf/.otf fonts.
          extra_fonts: ./fonts/*.ttf

          # Arbitrary bash codes to be executed before compiling LaTeX documents
          pre_compile: tlmgr update --self && tlmgr update --all

          # Arbitrary bash codes to be executed after compiling LaTeX documents
          post_compile: latexmk -c

          # Instruct latexmk to enable --shell-escape
          # latexmk_shell_escape: # optional

          # Instruct latexmk to use LuaLaTeX
          # latexmk_use_lualatex: # optional

          # Instruct latexmk to use XeLaTeX
          latexmk_use_xelatex: true 

    - name: Check pdf file
      run: |
        file resume_aditya_wagh.pdf | grep -q ' PDF '

    - name: Upload file to repository
      run: |
        git config --global user.name "adityamwagh"
        git config --global user.email "adityamwagh@gmail.com"
        git add resume_aditya_wagh.pdf
        git commit -m "commit message"
        git push
      if: github.event_name == 'push' && github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'
```